# ASP.NET CheckBox inside a hidden DIV always returns false

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net, webforms

I have some set of form elements within a hidden div as follows:

```
<div id="jDivUpdateFolder" style="display:none;">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditFolderName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditFolderDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:FileUpload ID="fuEditPhoto" runat="server" /><br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditContentOrder" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Ascending"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Descending"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditIsActive" runat="server" Text="Active" /><br />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEditShowOnHome" runat="server" Text="Show on HomePage" /><br />
    <asp:LinkButton CssClass="anchorbutton green" ID="btnSaveEditFolder" Text="Save" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I toggle the visibility of this div via a function in jQuery (not including it here for simplicity purposes)

When the form is submitted with the click event of btnSaveEditFolder, I can retreive all the values of the TextBoxes, FileUpload control and the DropDownList correctly. But somehow, checkboxes always return false. I am going nuts on this..

```
Protected Sub btnSaveEditFolder_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveEditFolder.Click
    Dim fID As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtFolderID.Value.Trim) ' value is good
    Dim fname As String = txtEditFolderName.Text.Trim ' value is good
    Dim fdesc As String = txtEditFolderDesc.Text.Trim ' value is good
    Dim order As String = IIf(ddlEditContentOrder.SelectedItem.Value = "0", "Asc", "Desc") ' value is good
    Dim isactive As Boolean = IIf(chkEditIsActive.Checked, True, False) ' ## ALWAYS FALSE
    Dim isvisible As Boolean = IIf(chkEditShowOnHome.Checked, True, False) ' ## ALWAYS FALSE
End Sub
```

When I remove the style `display:block;` and the form is visible on page to start with, then they return correct values (true if checked, false if not..)

Anyone came accross such problem?

Comment: Can you please post the code on how you change the checkbox value ? Probably you use javascript if this is hidden , correct ?

Comment: Yes I use javascript but only to hide/show the div itself. I don't have any client side code to check/uncheck checkboxes.

Comment: Interestingly, I copy & paste your code above onto a test page and both checkboxes return the expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the checkbox's value to true:

```
value="True"
```

Post and let me know if that works. Sounds silly but just do it and holler back if that does the trick if not I'll look into it further for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim isactive As Boolean = chkEditIsActive.Checked
```